# If we have the joint probability function of X and Y, how can we derive that of X and -Y?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given $\displaystyle F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\operatorname {P} (X\leq x,Y\leq y)$, what is the relationship with $\displaystyle F_{X,-Y}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
F_{X,-Y}(x,y)=\mathsf{P}(X\le x,Y\ge -y)=\mathsf{P}(X\le x)-\mathsf{P}(X\le x,Y< -y).
$$
If $F_{X,Y}$ is continuous,
$$
F_{X,-Y}(x,y)=F_X(x)-F_{X,Y}(x,-y).
$$